# Loop outcome separated by whitespace

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am trying to display all non-divisibles by 3 and 7 with whitespace between each number.
However I am a bit struggling with the whitespaces. This is how my outcome should look like: "1 2 4 5 8 10"!

I appreciate your help!

```
let input = 10;
let i = " ";

for(var num = 1; num <= input; num++ ){
      if(num % 3 != 0 && num % 7 != 0){
         i = i + num;
   }
}
console.log(i);
```

Comment: Start with empty string: `i=""`.
At each iteration of the loop:
`num%3*num%7` will be Zero if `num` is either a multiple of 3 or 7.
If not Zero: concatenate `num` to `i`,
If Zero: concatenate "nothing" to `i`: `""`.
If concatenating: If not last `num`, add a space `" "`, if last, add "nothing".
`input=10;
i="";
for(var num=1; num<=input; num++)
  i+=num%3*num%7?num+(num==input?"":" "):"";
console.log("i=\""+i+"\"");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add spaces while modifying `i`. Also, remember to remove trailing whitespace at the and of the resulting string using `.trimEnd()`:

```js
let input = 10;
let i = "";

for(var num = 1; num <= input; num++ ){
      if(num % 3 != 0 && num % 7 != 0){
         i = i + num + " "; // <-- here
   }
}
i = i.trimEnd(); // <-- and here
console.log(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let input = 10;
let i = " ";

for(var num = 1; num <= input; num++ ){
   if(num % 3 != 0 && num % 7 != 0){
     i = i + num + " ";
   }
}
console.log(i);
```

Comment: thanks for helping on my rookie question :) appreciated